# How to have react-router in electrode app push in an action file

Tags: react-router, walmart-electrode

I have a react app using the walmart electrode framework with uses react router.  My question is

a) how can push a route during an action trigger?  I tried importing push from react-router but I got a method not found error.  I tried instead to use browserHistory.push and that sets the url but for some reason login renders only at /#/login?_k=jazzx rather than at /login.

b) how can I get it to do the /resoure urls rather than the hash #/resource urls.  It's a single page app.  I realize that it's doing that because its a single page app, but Is there a setting for that?  Whats the best practice?

c) what is the querystring that electrode is attaching to things - is that for dev only?

```
export const tryLogin = (returnUrl = '/') => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    browserHistory.push('/login');  //this doesn't seem to render the route /#/login_k=somestring does work
    return dispatch(createLoginAction({ returnUrl }));
  };
}
```

;

Answer (score 0):

The URL `/#/login?_k=jazzx` implies that you are using a hash history, but you are attempting to change the URL using `browserHistory`. You should be passing the `browserHistory` to your `<Router>` if you want to use the browser history API (aka have clean URLs).

If you use the `browserHistory`, you will need to have some sort of code on your server to handle routing set up.